# Count records between timespan of an hour in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to read data from csv file with records like this:

> Lane 4 Op2, 2259,13:03:50, 100%, 209, 0:02:26

And I need to count amount of records appearing within the same hour. This is the farthest I was able to achieve.

```
data = pd.read_csv('2021-07-30.csv',  parse_dates=['hour'], infer_datetime_format=True)
datafiltr = data[data.lane=="Lane 4 Op2"]
datafiltr['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(datafiltr['hour'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = datafiltr.resample('H', on='hour').agg({'detal':'sum'})
amount = (df.iloc[0][0]/datafiltr.iloc[1][1])
int_array = amount.astype(int)
```

But I'm not quite satisfied with the result, I'd love to receive any tips. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas [dt.hour](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html#pandas-series-dt-hour) to get only the hours of the datetime. Then, use `value_counts` to have the amount of records appearing within the same hour.

*sample.csv*

```py
            0     1         2     3    4        5
0    Lane4Op2  2259  13:03:50  100%  209  0:02:26
1    Lane4Op2  2596  19:35:00    1%  209  0:02:26
2    Lane4Op2  2325  15:50:00   72%  209  0:02:26
3    Lane4Op2  1516  20:02:00   63%  209  0:02:26
4    Lane4Op2  2391  12:35:00   78%  209  0:02:26
..        ...   ...       ...   ...  ...      ...
96   Lane4Op2  1924  07:52:00   70%  209  0:02:26
97   Lane4Op2  2223  00:22:00   15%  209  0:02:26
98   Lane4Op2  1621  23:07:00   86%  209  0:02:26
99   Lane4Op2  2386  01:02:00   82%  209  0:02:26
100  Lane4Op2  2437  18:05:00   63%  209  0:02:26
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=None)
print(df)

datetime = pd.to_datetime('01/01/2021'+' '+df[2])
dt_count = datetime.dt.hour.value_counts()
dt_count = dt_count.sort_index()

ax = dt_count.plot.bar()
plt.xticks(dt_count.index.values)
plt.show()
```

[image: timespan]